# How to poll anonymously?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for an idea to develop a little poll system that voters be able to vote anonymously. No registration, no e-mail ..., Of course, everyone must vote only ONE time.

I do not want to use cookies, because I think it's possible that a few users vote from one machine, or one user votes with several browsers on a machine. Also I think working with IP addresses is not a good idea too, because it is possible users use proxy. So, do you have any idea for this?

(I use ASP.NET 4 with C# & SQL Server 2008)

Thanks.

Comment: Search the web for "uniquely identify website visitor".

Comment: IP or cookies. Neither guarantees anything, but that's your only options without registration. Most anon-polls used to be based on 'persistent' cookies. Or cookies with long lifespan like 5-20 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to guarantee that each person will only vote once, without registration. Even if you get the IP, you will fail to prevent this person from voting a second time from another location and you will prevent multiple persons from voting using the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Without registration your best bet is to use IP adress to identify votes. Store polls in a database and refuse to update if the voter is trying to vote more than once.

A way to get IP address:

```
public static string getIPAddress(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string szRemoteAddr = request.UserHostAddress;
    string szXForwardedFor = request.ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    string szIP = "";

    if (szXForwardedFor == null)
    {
        szIP = szRemoteAddr;
    }
    else
    {
        szIP = szXForwardedFor;
        if (szIP.IndexOf(",") > 0)
        {
            string [] arIPs = szIP.Split(',');

            foreach (string item in arIPs)
            {
                if (!isPrivateIP(item))
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return szIP;
}
```